# Use Anova to compare changes in categorical variable over time in R

Tags: r, proportions

I am trying to compare the prescribing of 7 medications pre and post an intervention in 3 groups. I have columns for each other medications with flags of 1 or 0 if prescribed and labels that are pre_econ, post_econ, pre_nocon, post_nocon, pre_inp, post_inp.

The data are formatted like this:

[image]

I would like to compare the change in prescribing of the medications (flag = 1) for each other groups so I would get something like this:

[image]

I tried prop.table but I do not know how to take the calculated percentages and make a change (from pre post) or how to compare the change.

Comment: You need to show sample data  before you have done any calculation of percentages.

Comment: Please share your data in code format if you can - run `dput(data)` and paste the result in your question. This way, we will be able to try coding a solution ourselves - we can't import a screenshot of data into R.

Comment: Also what does each row represent? Why are there 12 rows for each intervention and not just 2? Are these 6 patients?

Comment: @AndreaM I was able to select the first 100 rows and run dput, but it will not let me copy and paste the results here. Each patient has 2 rows for pre and post but I did not include the patient column.